# xunit not taking long strings from constants into theory (.net core)

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, xunit

Can someone tell me why XUnit is only recognizing the second constant in the example below?  The below code will only run the Theory with the second constant.  I'm completely stumped.

```
namespace DocumentStore.IntegrationTests
{
public static class Constants
{
    public const string Test1 = "https://documentstore1.dev.namespace.net/v2/service.svc/basicNoAuth";

    public const string Test2 = "https://documentstore1.dev.namespace.net/v2/service.svc";
}

public class Tests
{
    [Theory]
    [InlineData(Constants.Test1)]
    [InlineData(Constants.Test2)]
    public void ExampleTest(string url)
    {
        var test = url;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me and should work. You can try [MemberData(nameof(Test1), MemberType= typeof(Constants))].

Comment: That's what is puzzling to me.  The above code does not work.  If those strings are shortened, it will work but that's not useful to me as my actual URL's that I need to test are longer than the ones above and the theory will only run with the second InlineData parameter (Test2 in the example above).

Comment: What versions of xunit\vs\.net you are using? Try replicate on a brand new project with latest versions?

Comment: Tried in xUnit 2.4.1.0. Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I also found that if a parameter value is too long xUnit treats the two theories as the same because the truncated values are the same. Super lame but here is a hack I used to get around it. I added a `theoryIndex` to make sure they are unique

```
namespace DocumentStore.IntegrationTests
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public const string Test1 = "https://documentstore1.dev.namespace.net/v2/service.svc/basicNoAuth";
        public const string Test2 = "https://documentstore1.dev.namespace.net/v2/service.svc";
    }

    public class Tests
    {
        [Theory]
        [InlineData(Constants.Test1, 0)]
        [InlineData(Constants.Test2, 1)]
        public void ExampleTest(string url, int theoryIndex)
        {
            var test = url;
        }
    }
}
```